# Sorting a two dimensions array using second level values

Tags: php, sorting

I have a 2 dimensions array and need to sort it according to some of the second dimension values.
I tried using `uksort`, but it doesn't work:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array('name'=>'test1', 'age'=>25);
$arr[] = array('name'=>'test2', 'age'=>22);
$arr[] = array('name'=>'test3', 'age'=>23);
$arr[] = array('name'=>'test4', 'age'=>29);
uksort($arr, "cmp");
print_r($arr);

function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['age']==$b['age']) return 0;
    return ($a['age'] < $b['age']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Can anyone spot what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

[`uksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) will order your array by keys, but you want to sort the arrays by their value.

Answer (score 0):

`uksort`

> Sort an array by **keys** using a user-defined comparison function

Sorting array by keys means that you take **value of a key** (in your case it is the same string `age` for all subarrays). And you sort by **value**.

So `usort` is enough - [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/XPgkV).